# Artikel Zusammenfassung

Tags: article

Ich versuche die Grammatik zu wiederholen. Hier das, was ich so weit weiß:

- Wir haben **bestimmte Artikel** (der, das, die, den, des, ...) in verschiedener Form (Nominative, Akkusative, Dative, Genetiv).
- Wir haben **unbestimmte Artikel** (ein, eine, einige, ...) in verschiedener Form.
- Wir haben **Negationsartikel** (kein, keine, ...) in verschiedener Form.

Meine Fragen sind:

1. Ich glaube die folgenden sind auch Artikel, aber ich weiß nicht zu welcher Kategorie kann ich diese Artikel zählen:

   - dies (diese, dieses, ...)
   - denen
   - dessen
2. Können wir die folgende als Artikel bezeichnen?

   - irgend
   - jede
   - alle
   - beide
   - jemand
3. Gibt es andere Artikel, die ich noch nicht aufgezählt habe. Ich frage weil ich möchte keine Überraschung mit neuen Artikeln erleben.

Comment: Wir kennen noch Kosmetik- und Elektroartikel.

Answer (score 4):

Du bringst [Determinative](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinativ_(Wortart)) und Artikel durcheinander.

Artikel sind nur:

- **bestimmte Artikel**

  > der die das des dem den

  Beispiel:

  > **Der** Baum steht im Garten.
- **unbestimmte Artikel**

  > ein eine eines einer einem einen

  Beispiel:

  > **Ein** Baum steht im Garten.

Manchmal zählt man auch den Nullartikel zu den Artikel (Damit ist das Fehlern eines Artikels an einer Stelle gemeint, an der man aus bestimmten grammatikalischen Überlegungen heraus einen Artikel erwarten würde.)

- **Nullartikel**

  > 

  Beispiel:

  > Bäume stehen im Garten.
  >   (Das nicht vorhandene Wort vor »Bäume« ist ein Nullartikel.)

---

Alles andere was du aufgezählt hast, sind keine Artikel!

Insbesondere sind auch die Wörter *kein, keine* usw. keine Artikel, sondern Indefinitpronomen.

Aber Indefinitpronomen (zu denen auch *etwas, jeder, viele* und einige mehr gehören), gehören gemeinsam mit den Artikeln zu den Derminativen.

Manchmal werden Determinative auch »Artikelwörter« genannt, aber diese Bezeichnung ist irreführend, weil die meisten Determinative eben keine Artikel sind.

Zu den Determinativen gehören (die meisten Beispiele stammen aus dem oben verlinkten Wikipedia-Artikel):

- **Artikel**

  > der, ein, ...
  >
  > Hast du **das** Känguru gesehen?
  >   Hast du schon mal **ein** Känguru gesehen?
- **Demonstrativpronomina**

  > dieser, jener, der
  >
  > Hast du **dieses** Känguru schon mal gesehen?
  >   Hast du **jenes** Känguru schon mal gesehen?
  >   Ach, **das** Känguru dort drüben hast du gemeint!
- **Interrogativpronomina**

  > wessen, welcher, ...
  >
  > **Wessen** Känguru meinst du?
  >   **Welches** Känguru meinst du?
  >   **Was für ein** Känguru meinst du?
  >   **Wie viele** Kängurus leben in diesem Tierheim?

  Anmerkung zu »was für ein«: Das sind zwar drei Wörter, aber wenn diese drei so wie hier gemeinsam verwendet werden, gelten sie zusammen als ein Interrogativpronomen, denn »was für ein(e)« ist ein exaktes Synonym für »welche(r/s)«.

  Anmerkung zu »wie viel(e)«: Das ist zwar kein Synonym eines einzelnen Wortes, erfüllt aber, wie auch »was für ein« genau die grammatische Funktion eines Interrogativpronomens, und wird daher oftmals gemeinsam mit Interrogativpronomen behandelt. (Auf jeden Fall gehört »wie viel(e)« zu den Determinativen)
- **Possessivpronomina**

  > mein, dein, unser, ...
  >
  > **Mein** Känguru ist viel klüger als **Ihr** Delphin.
- **Indefinitpronomina**

  > kein, jeder, alle, ...
  >
  > Hier ist **kein** Känguru vorbeigesprungen.
  >   **Alle** Kängurus sind Beuteltiere.
  >   Ich habe schon **einige** Kängurus gesehen.